# Valgrind out of memory

Tags: c++, valgrind

This is the message I get when valgrind crashes and stops profiling my app:

```
    ==16317== 
    ==16317==     Valgrind's memory management: out of memory:
    ==16317==        newSuperblock's request for 4194304 bytes failed.
    ==16317==        3013349376 bytes have already been allocated.
    ==16317==     Valgrind cannot continue.  Sorry.
    ==16317== 
    ==16317==     There are several possible reasons for this.
    ==16317==     - You have some kind of memory limit in place.  Look at the
    ==16317==       output of 'ulimit -a'.  Is there a limit on the size of
    ==16317==       virtual memory or address space?
    ==16317==     - You have run out of swap space.
    ==16317==     - Valgrind has a bug.  If you think this is the case or you are
    ==16317==     not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
    ==16317==     Please note that programs can take substantially more memory than
    ==16317==     normal when running under Valgrind tools, eg. up to twice or
    ==16317==     more, depending on the tool.  On a 64-bit machine, Valgrind
    ==16317==     should be able to make use of up 32GB memory.  On a 32-bit
    ==16317==     machine, Valgrind should be able to use all the memory available
    ==16317==     to a single process, up to 4GB if that's how you have your
    ==16317==     kernel configured.  Most 32-bit Linux setups allow a maximum of
    ==16317==     3GB per process.
    ==16317== 
    ==16317==     Whatever the reason, Valgrind cannot continue.  Sorry.
```

I 've tried using huge swap files but it doesn't get better.
The crash happens long before my swap file is nearly full.
I 'm using Fedora 19.
Does anyone know anything about this?I think I read something on the internet about how there may be a limit to the memory a single process can allocate.If this is the case ,where can I set it?At least give me a good alternative to valgrind people :P.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Judging from the title I'd say you've got some memory leaks. You should run it through- crap.

Answer (score 0):

" Most 32-bit Linux setups allow a maximum of 3GB per process."

You've allocated 3013349376 bytes, which is awfully close to 3GB. So you probably have a 32-bit OS, and you're just running out of memory for a single process (the other ~200 megs are probably valgrind overhead)